# pgSQL - trigger function before INSERT check if record with same id exists

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have a task:
Before INSERT check if record with same id exists, to set for a new record time_dead()

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.id = OLD.id THEN
         INSERT INTO temporary_objects(OLD.time_dead)
         value(now());
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

This doesn't work, as OLD and INSERT don't work together.
But I don't see an alternative.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this situation in a couple of ways:

1. You can use INSERT or UPDATE if you have a primary key defined on the id column of the table:
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

```
INSERT INTO temporary_objects VALUES(NEW.*) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET time_dead = now();
```

2. You can put logic in the trigger to find the row with NEW.id, if NEW.id doesn't exists then INSERT a new record else UPDATE. Something like given below:

```
   DECLARE
      id_exists INTEGER;
   BEGIN
     SELECT id INTO id_exists FROM temporary_objects WHERE id = NEW.id;
     IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO temporary_objects VALUES(NEW.*);
     ELSE 
         UPDATE temporary_objects SET time_dead = now() WHERE id = NEW.id;
         RETURN NEW;
     END IF;
     RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I get a syntax error, while copying your second variant. Ty

Comment: Corrected: 4 LINE: SELECT INTO